# How to change the text color of eclipse(kepler) text editor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to make my eclipse Dark theme so I install moonrise theme in my window preferences. But the Text color stays the same and its hard for me to read my code. can anyone help me and provide step by step process to change the text color of my text editor? thank you.[image]

Comment: Kepler is a bit old now, [Luna added official support](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/11/dark-eclipse-ships-with-eclipse-luna/) and it was improved by Mars. If you can, try to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Since yours image shows a Java editor.

You have to go to Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor-Syntax coloring to change the text colors.

For any text editors you can go to Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text editors to change the foreground color.

Hope this helps.

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: Its hard change the color of every element. is there any text theme that fits on monrise theme? if it exist, how can import it to my eclipse?